# How to return email address when auth an OpenID?

Tags: php, email, openid

I'm trying to build a login form using OpenID Auth. I'm using sample code from: http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/ But I only get user's email address when auth with account on myopenid.com I want get returned email when auth link "google.com/accounts/o8/id" How can I do? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no guarantee that a particular OpenID will be backed up by an email address.

To get that level of user data, you'll need to look into the "persona" part of the OpenID system

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I don't understand your answer completely. I think every OpenId must have a correlative email address. What's wrong?

Comment: No, not at all. An OpenID is just a URL. A *Google* account of course has an email address attached to it, but there's no guarantee that [provider X] will use an email address (it might just have a username/password, for example). Even if it does, I might choose to keep it private from sites I'm logging into - that's one of the benefits of OpenID

Answer (score 1):

You must use the AX extension instead of the Simple Registration extension. You also must "require" the email attribute instead of marking it as optional.

Special requirements for Google.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The simple code used the SReg class right. I'll try with AX. If I'm not success, I'll ask again :D.